# Bind in constructor or fat arrow in class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i'm wondering if there is a difference between this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page : 1
    };
  }

  nextPage = () => {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
  }

  previousPage= () => {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 });
  }

  render() {
    const { page } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <H1>{page}</H1>
        <Button onClickPrevious={this.previousPage} onClickNext={this.nextPage} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Example extends Component {   
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
         this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
         this.state = {
              page: 1
             };
  }

  nextPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });   }

  previousPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 });   }

  render() {
    const { page } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <H1>{page}</H1>
        <Button onClickPrevious={this.previousPage} onClickNext={this.nextPage} />}
      </div>
    );   
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if it's the same in performance this to every function or are there any other benefits?

a bit of further reading(https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f#.khf30fuaq)

Comment: Neither the bind nor the fat arrow is required, as you are extending from `Component` react binds these functions for you

Comment: @Dogoku `class` methods are not bound implicitly

Comment: I read the question again, you are right

Answer (score 4):

The best place to bind your event handlers is your `constructor`. This way your event handler has its context bound to the component instance.You can access `props and state` and call `setState` or `forceUpdate` from such bound handler.

Binding with `arrow` functions have their own advantages as well.
Arrow functions always gets the context from where they have been defined. So in fact, this example is equivalent to:

The arrow function syntax is a way of defining function with a syntax like this:

```
change = (ev) => this.setState({ text: ev.target.value });
```

It is a more concise way than writing a `function(ev) { .... }` statement. If you don’t provide `{` and `}` brackets after the `=>` arrow, such function is a single expression which is returned instantly. So this desugars to something like:

```
change = function(ev) { return this.setState({ text: ev.target.value }); }.bind(this);
```

And hence both of `.bind()` and `arrow` function cause a new function to be created

Concluding, the way you want to bind your function depends on your use case.

For more details you can read up **[this](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/)** article:

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But you are saying if you bind this in the constructor you can access state and props. But in the first example (where i didn't implicitly bind my function) i can change the state. Both examples just work fine (because i use the fat arrow function that will bind the context, right?).

Comment: In the oldest component class syntax called React.createClass binding problem is non-existent. That is because React.createClass performs auto-binding under the hood. All methods you define in an object passed to React.createClass will be automatically bound to the component instance. That means you can always use setState, access props and state and so on from these methods. quote: http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/