# Getting error Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new with Reactjs. I'm trying to do something very simple: update a div inside a render function when the user change the text inside text area. Any suggestions?

```js
class HTMLEditor extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'Put here HTML'};
  }
  
  
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.currentTarget.value});
  }
 
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <textarea defaultValue={this.state.value} onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        <div>{this.state.value}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HTMLEditor />, 
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: you just have to bind `handleChange` to the component. Add `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` in the constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should bind the `handleChange` function. You are getting this error because, in your handleChange function `this` keywork doesn't refer to the context of the React Class and hence you need to bind the function.

See this answer on **[`why do you need to bind event handlers in React`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-do-we-need-to-bind-function-and-eventhandlers-in-react-and-what-is-the-diffe/41113862#41113862)**

```js
class HTMLEditor extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'Put here HTML'};
  }
  
  
  handleChange = (e) =>{
    this.setState({value: e.currentTarget.value});
  }
 
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <textarea defaultValue={this.state.value} onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        <div>{this.state.value}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HTMLEditor />, 
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Great, thank for both of you!! Can you please explain what is the difference between this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this) vs arrow function and what is better as a best practice? 
Thanks

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760646/bind-in-constructor-or-fat-arrow-in-class